# HQL join query: Path expected for join

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I'm new to hql, I referred to a site to write hql query in Spring Framework, but it throws "Path expected for join!" exception

My query is

```
"from GaugeCateSelect cs inner join PreferredUrl purl on cs.survey=purl.survey where purl.uuid=:uuid"
```

I want to connect both table with "**survey**".

How can I sort it out?

### Update

Two tables, names are *GaugeCateSelect* and *PreferredUr*l. The "survey" field is common for both table. *uuid* is in PreferredUrl. I want to get all data from GaugeCateSelect when I pass the uuid to PreferredUrl table. (In short, Pass uuid to PreferredUrl, then find the survey number from PreferredUrl  and check the number with GaugeCateSelect table, if exists get all data)

### Update 2

There is no *primary/foreign key reference relationship* between two tables. but *common field survey* is there

**GaugeCateSelect class**

```
class GaugeCateSelect {
        
    private int id; 
    private String categoryName;    
    private int posNeg; 
    private Survey survey;  //survey is in foreign key relationship of survey table

//Annotation, getters and setters were removed for easiness.

}
```

**PreferredUrl class**

```
public class PreferredUrl {
    
    private int preferredUrlId;
    private String uuid;
    private int enabled;
    private Survey survey;  //survey is in foreign key relationship of survey table

//Annotation, getters and setters were removed for easiness.

}
```

Comment: Can you add the annotation on the fields Survey? Thanks

Comment: yes i added, but does not work

Comment: Add them in your question, so that we can see them!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the Hibernate version you use as there is a difference when joining unrelated entities as discussed here: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/